# Allowing only specific components to manipulate observables in services that are shared across multiple components in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-services

I've created a service with a private `Subject<T>` and a public `Observable<T>` that corresponds with it, and I'd like to inject the service into multiple components so that they can access the `Observable<T>`. However, I only want to allow specific components to push new data into the `Subject<T>` while the others may only subscribe or bind to the `Observable<T>`.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedDataService {

  // Allow specific components to manipulate this but not others
  private changingData$: Subject<T> = new BehaviorSubject<T>(undefined);

  // Allow all components to read this data, but not change it
  data$: Observable<T> = this.changingData$.asObservable();

  /* Rest of the implementation here... */
}
```

The service is shared with components that are rendered by a `router-outlet` so I can't simply pass on the data with an `@Input` property. I believe it's also not possible to pass observables as router data, so that's another dead end.

As a temporary solution, I've simply implemented a `pushData(T data): void` method inside the service to at least allow the data to change, but this of course allows every component to potentially push data into it.

I've also looked into multi providers in Angular but I'm not sure if they fit my use case. I could have a read-only service and a read-and-write service that implement the same base interface exposing the `Observable<T>` but I'm not sure how I would hook them up inside the specific components that *are* allowed to push data.

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: @Lonli-Lokli is there a different approach I could take then?

Comment: I'ts not possible due to javascript world, you cannot have access to one property and not another. Possible way is to use separate services and do not share pub-one to the public

Comment: @Lonli-Lokli I see, I'll try to work something out, thanks!